# Unparseable date: "2017-01-02T01:41:24Z" (at offset 10)

Tags: android, date, simpledateformat, unparseable

`2017-01-02T01:41:24Z` is my actual date format and I want to convert this date in `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mma` format.

Please see the following code I tried so far,

```
  String newsDate = "2017-01-02T01:41:24Z";
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mma");
        Date date = null;
        try
        {
            date = sdf.parse(newsDate);
        }
        catch (ParseException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

but at `date = sdf.parse(newsDate);` line I'm getting the following error:

> "Unparseable date: "2017-01-02T01:41:24Z" (at offset 10)".

Please guide me, where could i have gone wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are using different Date Format which is not correct.

Change this

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mma");
```

to this

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   String newsDate = "2017-01-02T01:41:24Z";    
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
   SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mma");

   try {
        texview.setText(sdf1.format(sdf.parse(newsDate)));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          System.out.println("bad pattern");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly for me.

```
 String dateNew= "2017-01-02T01:41:24Z";

 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
 SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mma");


try {
    texview.setText(sdf1.format(sdf.parse(dateNew)));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.out.println("bad pattern");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are wrong with respect to time zone / offset - interpretation. The trailing "Z" denotes UTC+00:00 and must not be interpreted just as literal. The [documentation of Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#iso8601timezone) defines the suitable pattern symbol X which can handle this kind of input. If you don't care about this detail then you will not get an exception but wrong data (which is even worse).

So the final solution including the fix for the hour-part looks like:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
```

Note: Use XX instead of XXX if you have offsets without colon.